# Where do I place additional form controls in my visual studio ASP.net webform project

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio

I am trying to add an additional combo box form control to my ASP.net web form in visual studio 2010.

Where should I place an unzipped folder containing a control? how do I add the new control to my 'tools'

Really appreciated, this is driving me nuts
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Some of this is down to personal preference.

I like to have a folder outside of my projects where toolbox items can go so : c:\VS2015Tools\

As for adding the items, you can right click on the toolbox and select "choose items"

You can then browse to the DLL that you have unzipped by clicking on the "browse" button

[image]

If you have a project with the source for the server control, include the project in your solution and it *should* automatically be picked up and added to the toolbox (Though Ive found this to be hit or miss as to whether it works)

Hope that helps, sorry its not very detailed.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! typically the downloads don't include dll or executable files. They include a Microsoft visual studio solution files, Bin, Object, Properties directories and a number of C+ files. Not sure how to deploy this....any suggestions? Really appreciated Dan

Comment: Where did you get the controls from? Do you have a link that I can download them from?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/script/articles/download.aspx?file=/KB/combobox/CheckComboBox/CheckComboBox.zip&rp=http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18929/An-OwnerDraw-ComboBox-with-CheckBoxes-in-the-Drop